# NSMutableArray endless loop

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, infinite-loop

I'm using xcode5.0 no ARC.

Here is the code(.h):

```
@interface MatchmakingServer : NSObject{}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *connectedClients;

- (void)doSomething;
@end
```

.mm file:

```
#import "MatchmakingServer.h"

@implementation MatchmakingServer

@synthesize connectedClients;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)doSomething 
{
    self.connectedClients = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
    NSLog(@"%d", self.connectedClients.count);
}
@end
```

And when the code hit the `NSLog(@"%d", self.connectedClients.count);` it enters an endless loop

I tried to add a breakpoint before NSLog and I saw:

```
connectedClients    __NSArrayM *    @"0 objects"    0x0be9c440
```

in debugger.

More information: I'm mixing oc and cpp I don't know if that's what caused the problem.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Show us your backtrace (type "bt" in the debugger pane and hit Enter to get it).

Comment: Do you override the property getter? Your example doesn't include it, but if you did I could foresee some issues.

Comment: what is calling `-doSomething`?

Comment: How do you know the endless loop is on the NSLog, and not on what's calling `doSomething`? Have you put a breakpoint and stepped over to see where the code goes?

Comment: Don't expect it to print `3 objects` though, your array is still empty no matter what you set with `arrayWithCapacity:`

Comment: Why is the property `assign` and not `strong`?

Comment: assign and no arc and no alloc init your array does not exist

Comment: @NicolasManzini Yes, his array exists until the autorelease pool is drained.

Comment: @NicolasManzini calling `arrayWithCapacity` automatically `alloc init's` the array.

Comment: @JoelFischer No `arrayWithCapacity:` return an autoreleased object. But since is property is `assign` and not `retain` the object is released at the end of the method.

Comment: To the few posts above:  the OP is inquiring about an endless loop.  You guys are detracting from the topic.

Comment: there is no endless loop